Apache Ranger with ElasticSearch audit store without solr
I have configured Apache Ranger and elasticSearch as audit store but when I login to Ranger UI and click on Audit Tab, I see popup message "Error! Error running solr query, please check solr configs. Server refused connection at: http://localhost:6083/solr/ranger_audits
"

My question is since I am using elasticSearch why Audit is still using Solr vs elasticsearch or do I need to install Solr setup as well.
Apache Ranger version is ranger-2.4.0

install.properties file under ranger-admin have following property set

audit_store=elasticsearch
audit_elasticsearch_urls=localhost
audit_elasticsearch_port=9200
audit_elasticsearch_protocol=http
audit_elasticsearch_user=elastic
audit_elasticsearch_password=mypassword
audit_elasticsearch_index=ranger_audits
audit_elasticsearch_bootstrap_enabled=true

#audit_solr_urls=http://localhost:6083/solr/ranger_audits
audit_solr_urls=
audit_solr_user=
audit_solr_password=
audit_solr_zookeepers=

